# Enable Java syntax highlight in SourceForge's hgweb

Tags: sourceforge, hgweb

I would like to have syntax highlighting in hgweb.

For example, makes

http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/file/7289237e7b67/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/AboutJDialog.java

looks like

http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstock/jstock/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/AboutJDialog.java?revision=1.36&view=markup

May I know how I can do so? I saw

https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Mercurial%20Web%20repository%20browser mentions `Viewing the contents of a checked-in file (including raw or syntax-highlighted outputs).`.

May I know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enable the syntax-highlighting via mime-type setting. I have done this with svn via setting the svn property svn:mime-type for files:
xml to text/xml
java to text/x-java

Next check in the files and the syntax should be highlighted.

For other scm tools please check there manual, how to set the mime-type for check in.

I hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: Here is a link to automate setting of mime-type for svn:
http://mikewest.org/2006/06/working-with-subversion-file-properties

Comment: Here is my auto property file to import in eclipse:
https://gist.github.com/raw/1551414/a48d7000a891d9db7cec39fb22f162bd3e2d451d/svn-properties.config